# Why is Azure Portal suddenly requiring OpenID Connect Scopes for a registered app's claims?

Tags: azure, authentication, azure-active-directory, azureportal, claims

I have several apps registered on the Azure Portal of the company I work for that have the following optional claims: email, family_name, given_name, and upn. When I added those claims everything went fine and there were no errors or warnings. The registered apps are used for authenticating an ASP.NET Core 2.2 applications. The returned ID tokens contain those claims and I am able to use them within my application.

Not long ago I noticed that I started getting this warning when visiting the 'Token configuration' page of registered applications:
[image: These claims (email, upn, family_name, given_name) require OpenID Connect Scopes to be configured through the API Permissions Page. Go to API Permissions]
and on each claim in the table there is a warning icon that says `This claim required OpenID Connect Scopes to be configured through the API permissions page`.

Also, when adding optional claims, I now receive this popup:
[image: Some of these claims (family_name, given_name, upn) require OpenId Connect scopes to be configured through the API permissions page or by checking the box below. Turn on the Microsoft Graph profile permission (required for claims to appear in token).]

If I press Add without checking the box, I get that warning on the 'Token configuration' page and only the `User.Read` permission is added to API permissions. If I check it, the warning goes away an additional `profile` permission is added.

This popup and warning seems to be something recent, but I didn't change anything in those registered apps. Whether the warning is there or not, I still get the claims in the ID token. In fact, [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/permissions-reference#remarks-16) says:
`The Microsoft Authentication Library (MSAL) currently specifies offline_access, openid, profile, and email by default in authorization and token requests. This means that, for the default case, if you specify these permissions explicitly, Azure AD may return an error.` This would explain why I still get the claims.

So, I have that warning but everything works fine, and if I specify `profile` permission explicitly Azure AD might return an error.

I don't have a great grasp of AzureAD and I'm not sure if I should add claims with that box checked. Why did does this warning start appearing? What would be the best course of action to handle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably a case of Portal, documentation and library teams being misaligned. As you've observed, MSAL libraries by default add these [OIDC permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-permissions-and-consent#openid-connect-scopes) to their token request APIs.

Now how come the permissions you haven't added on the Portal are still granted when MSAL requests these by default? The answer is [dynamic consent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-permissions-and-consent) -an Azure AD mechanism that allows you to specify the permissions you need on the go. Since the library request these permissions by default, everything works fine in your case.

My advice would be to check the documentation/repository of the specific MSAL library you use, and see if they suggest adding them explicitly (for instance, in MSAL.js, this is left to the developer, and will work either way). If so, just add them on the Portal as well, and get rid of the warning.